# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'null' for column `myapp`.`employees`.`state_id` in Laravel and Angular

Tags: angular, laravel

In a project I am using Angular-12 as frontend and Laravel-8 as backend.

Laravel:

```
$employee = Employee::find($id);
$employee->nationality_id = $request->nationality_id;
$employee->state_id = $request->state_id ?? '';
$employee->city_id = $request->city_id ?? '';
$employee->save();
```

Angular:

component:

```js
loadCountryData(event: any) {
  // this.profileInfoForm.patchValue({ state_id: null });
  if (event) {
    this.country_id = event.id;
    this.cstatesService.getStatesByCountry(this.country_id).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.cstates = data.results.states;
        this.state_id = '';
        // console.log(this.cstates);
      }
    );
  } else {
    this.country_id = '';
  }
}

loadStateData(event: any) {
  // this.profileInfoForm.patchValue({ city_id: null });
  if (event) {
    this.state_id = event.id;
    this.citiesService.fetchCitiesByState(this.state_id).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.cities = data.results.cities;
        this.city_id = '';
      }
    );
  } else {
    this.state_id = '';
  }
}

loadCityData(event: any) {
  if (event) {
    this.city_id = event.id;
  } else {
    this.city_id = '';
  }
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this._id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  this.updateEmployee();
  this.loadCountryData(event);
  this.loadStateData(event);
  this.loadCityData(event);
}

updateEmployee() {
  this.profileInfoForm = this.fb.group({
    nationality_id: ['', [Validators.required]],
    state_id: [''],
    city_id: [''],
  });
}

onSubmitProfile() {
  this.isSubmitted = true;

  // stop here if form is invalid
  if (this.profileInfoForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }
  this.isLoading = true;

  const formProfileData = this.profileInfoForm.getRawValue();
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('nationality_id', formProfileData.nationality_id);
  formData.append('state_id', formProfileData.state_id);
  formData.append('city_id', formProfileData.city_id);

  this.employeeService.updateProfile(this._id, formData).subscribe(res => {
    this.data = res;
    console.log(this.data);
    // console.log(this.data);
    this.tokenEditProfileHandler(res);
  });
  //  this.isLoading = false;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="nationality">Nationality:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
          <ng-select (change)="loadCountryData($event)" [items]="countries" [selectOnTab]="true" [searchable]="true" bindValue="id" bindLabel="nationality" placeholder="Select Nationality" [multiple]="false" [clearable]="true" required formControlName="nationality_id">
          </ng-select>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="fp.nationality_id.touched && fp.nationality_id.invalid">
          <div *ngIf="fp.nationality_id.hasError('required')">
            <div class="text-danger">
              Nationality is required!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="state_id">State of Origin:</label>
          <ng-select (change)="loadStateData($event)" [items]="cstates" [selectOnTab]="true" [searchable]="true" bindValue="id" bindLabel="name" placeholder="Select State of Origin" [multiple]="false" [clearable]="true" formControlName="state_id">
          </ng-select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="city_id">Town:</label>
          <ng-select (change)="loadCityData($event)" [items]="cities" [selectOnTab]="true" [searchable]="true" bindValue="id" bindLabel="name" placeholder="Select Town" [multiple]="false" [clearable]="true" formControlName="city_id">
          </ng-select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is a dependent dropdown. Whenever state_id is not selected I got this error:

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'null' for column `myapp`.`employees`.`state_id`

state_id, city_id are integers. But if there is value in it, it is inserted without any error.

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Comment: What does the migration look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Panagiotis. Your migration file for employees table must have the column modifier "nullable()", if this field isn't required on model save or create

```
...
$table->unsignedBigInteger("state_id")->nullable();
...
```

after that, change this statement

```
$employee->state_id = $request->state_id ?? '';
```

instead use it

```
$employee->state_id = $request->state_id ?? null;
```